# Which application determine or set the maildir in a mail server?

Tags: email, postfix-mta, dovecot, maildir

My question is about mail server configuration with postfix (smtp) and dovecot (imap,pop3), both of these application have to see the same path to the maildir, for example /var/vmail/my_domain/user/Maildir. So, which application determine or set the maildir or the path to it?

Answer (score 0):

In your case BOTH of applications sets the maildir path, but `postfix` define it for writing during local delivery, while `dovecot` define it for reading during POP/IMAP interactions.

This is an example of the bad configuration, widely spreaded over the numbers of howtos and manuals. You should never perform local delivery from the MTA like `postfix` or `exim`. You have to use LDA functionality from your POP/IMAP server like `dovecot` instead.

When you invoke dovecot's `dovecot-lda` for LDA then the single dovecot.conf is used to define storage path and the single service have r/w access to the sorage so you can secure storage by `600` permissions.

You can refer to the `dovecot`'s wiki to know how to move LDA functionality from the `postfix` to the `dovecot` https://wiki.dovecot.org/LDA/Postfix